# Remove a line from text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, text, text-files, line

I'm using vb.net windows form app. I want to remove line from list of lines.

So if the line in textbox exists on that list, to be remove from list, and file to be saved.

I have a file list.txt with list of numbers :

```
123-123
321-231
312-132
```

If I write in textbox : 321-231 and if list.txt contains that line then remove it.
so result need to be :

```
123-123
321-132
```

I was trying with this code :

```
 Dim lines() As String
  Dim outputlines As New List(Of String)
        Dim searchString As String = Textbox1.Text
         lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\list.txt")
         For Each line As String In lines
             If line.Contains(searchString) = True Then
                 line = ""  'Remove that line and save text file (here is my problem I think )
                 Exit For
             End If
         Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put each string as you process it in the `outputlines` list, unless it matches the value typed in, like this:

```
Dim lines() As String
Dim outputlines As New List(Of String)
Dim searchString As String = Textbox1.Text
lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\list.txt")

For Each line As String In lines
    If line.Contains(searchString) = False Then
        outputlines.Add(line)
    End If
Next
```

Now `outputlines` matches every line that did not match what was typed in by the user and you can write the contents of the `outputlines` list to file.