# How to remove a line of text from a txt file

Tags: vb.net

I have a txt file with a list of items in it, each item has its own line. I have this loop that looped through each line of the text file. But how do I delete the line once I have found it?

```
Dim item As String = lbxPrimary.SelectedItem
    For Each Line As String In File.ReadAllLines(storepath & "Primary Items.txt")
        If Line.Contains(item) = True Then
                'Delete line here
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a line from text file vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222681/remove-a-line-from-text-file-vb-net)

Comment: I can't see where in that answer was the line deleted.

Comment: @user3671863 - Then read it a bit more carefully until you understand it. It does exactly what you need.

Comment: Not making any sense to me sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `content()` into a [`List(Of String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to use its method [`List(Of T).Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove the first occurrence matching the specified argument.

```
Dim content() As String = File.ReadAllLines(storepath & "Primary Items.txt")
Dim list As List(Of String) = content.ToList
list.Remove(lbxPrimary.SelectedItem)
File.WriteAllLines(storepath & "Primary Items.txt", list)
```